# Accidentally ran "sudo chmod a+rx ~"

Tags: 12.04, server, permissions, ssh, chmod

I accidentally  ran `sudo chmod a+rx ~` on the system root rather than `sudo chmod a+rx myfolder`...

I ran
 
`sudo chmod -R a+rX myfolder/public_html`
then accidentally ran 
`sudo chmod a+rx ~`
instead of `sudo chmod a+rx myfolder`

This quote is from a site I was using as a guide...

> "The first command sets everything in your public_html directory to be
>   readable and accessible by all users on the system. The second command
>   sets your home directory to be the same way (though not all the files
>   in it, like we did with public_html). Note that the "X" in the first
>   command is capitalized."

In short, I'm not a permissions guru and have many users on our cloud server. I would like to set it back to something more secure so that our main ssh users are fine, but any ftp user won't exploit my terrible mistake.

Pardon my ignorance!

Comment: What user where you logged in at the time you ran the command? That command would only change the current user's home folder permisions (not the files and folders inside it since you did not use `-R`), not the complete system...

Comment: my personal user's account through ssh.

Comment: Read edit, since you did not use `-R` you actually only changed your user's home folder, not even the files and folders inside it.

Comment: My ~ is not set to /home, only my login directory. ~ holds a bunch of hidden files for profiles. Would this matter that ~ isn't actually home?

Comment: @Seth are you saying that `~` isn't `/home/your_user_name`?

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: `sudo chmod a+rx ~` will change that folder, and only that folder, not the folders and files inside it. To affect all files and folders inside `~` you would have needed to use the `-R` option, so you are sort of safe...

Comment: Awesome, that is reassuring. Thought I just opened up a door! Thank you for your time, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chmod go-wrx ~` or, if sudo caused it to change root's `~`, `sudo chmod go-wrx ~root`.
Note: if root isn't setup, and thus doesn't have a real home dir, don't use the second, as you may remove permissions from a communal area.

Comment: I ran it as sudo. What does that command actually do? Other than hopefully fix my issue haha

Comment: @Seth `chmod` changes permissions. The `go` means group and other. the `-wrx` means remove read, write and execute.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation... and this won't affect myself or the other main users, only user groups that we have created?

Comment: The first, yes. If you need the second (as you haven't clarified whether your user's home or root's home was effected) may have issues if root doesn't have a real home dir

Comment: I believe it was my root's home as I ran it as sudo, with a ~ directory already existing for hidden files and profiles

Comment: You ran the `chmod` command using `sudo`. That doesn't mean that `~` in your command points to `/root` (the root home). Your command changed the permissions of whatever folder `~` is set to.